# python - How do I properly install suds-jurko?

Tags: python-3.x, suds

Let me just get this out of the way - I'm new to just about everything about modules. I can just about guarantee I'm going to say or ask something stupid.

To the point - I need to do some autotask API magic, and to do so I need to make use of suds-jurko (since I'm running Python 3.4 and suds is outdated).
I've installed it through `py -m pip install suds_jurko` which gave me an .egg, which I used easy_install on. Still, no sign of suds_jurko to be found.

**Why can't I `import` suds-jurko, and why does it not show up in the help>>modules of IDLE?**

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973852/suds-install-error-no-module-named-client).  The import statement for suds-jurko is still `import suds`.