# suds-jurko ImportError: No module named core

Tags: python, pip, suds

I have a `suds-jurko==0.6` installed in my application. when running my 
application i cannot figure out why this is happening. My application runs in a docker container. This should work fine but why im getting this error?

```
  ImportError: No module named core
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myapp/tasks.py", line 60, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myapp/tasks.py", line 94, in task_1
    from myapp.services import MyService
  File "/home/worker/application/myapp/services.py", line 7, in <module>
    from suds.client import Client
  File "/home/worker/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    import suds.bindings.binding
  File "/home/worker/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 26, in <module>
    from suds.mx.literal import Literal as MxLiteral
  File "/home/worker/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/literal.py", line 23, in <module>
    from suds.mx.core import Core
```

To narrow down the problem the culprit is on this import:  `from suds.client import Client`. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Related: [suds install error: no module named client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973852/suds-install-error-no-module-named-client)

Comment: IIRC Suds is deprecated, [Zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is always a good alternative if you cannot get this working.

Comment: @Nordle thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Check that you have a file `/home/worker/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/mx/core.py`.

Comment: @phd looking good!

Comment: @phd it exists in the site-package dir

Comment: What happens if you do `from suds.mx.core import Core` in the interpreter?